# Joomla 1.5 JPagination for a custom template

Tags: templates, joomla, pagination

I am building a site with Joomla 1.5 and I need to add Pagination to some articles on the front-end of my clients website. The template is my own custom design and not one of Joomla's existing templates. Are there any tutorials out there for a beginners guide on how to do this? If you can't think of any, would anybody here be able to explain how to do this for me? Please feel free to treat as though I am a 5 year old =)

Thank-you!!

I hope someone can help!!

Comment: What do you mean by adding pagination to some article? Pagination in Joomla occurs when you set the com_content to show like x number of articles ... If there're more articles Joomla automatically create the navigation links at the bottom. This is what navigation is, if that's not what you mean please provide more details. Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ahmad... I finally got it and the solution seemed VERY simple once I figured it out... All I had to do was insert a page break (click a button called "Pagebreak" found under the article entry window of an existing article) right before entry that I want to carry on to the next page... The pagination is inserted automatically... If is anything else to concerning this topic please advise otherwise, Thank-you for your feedback everyone!!

Comment: You're talking about splitting the article into several smaller chunks ... This is a core function in Joomla it doesn't need any special coding. Glad you understand it =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it fits but from the Packt Cookbook for Yoomla 1.5 Templating the styling pagination part is online, which also explains a bit into thee works of pagination  :

http://www.packtpub.com/article/customizing-template-joomla-1.5